# Send Post type XML Request Webservice Java - Failure response

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I am executing the following java code to send XML request to webservice URL using java. I have looked at this link to create my script.
I am getting failure as the respone. I did a print of the XML string. XML is formed correctly with no issues.
I would need to know where I am going wrong and any guidance would be greatful at this time.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import sun.net.www.http.HttpClient;

public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    excutePost();
}
public static String excutePost() throws Exception {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
     try {
      //Create connection
    String targetURL="https://XXXXXX.html";
    System.out.println(targetURL);
    String urlParameters="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?  >\r\n<request>\r\n <control>\r\n  <senderid>XXXX</senderid>\r\n  <password>XXXX</password>\r\n  <controlid>ControlIdHere</controlid>\r\n  <uniqueid>false</uniqueid>\r\n  <dtdversion>3.0</dtdversion>\r\n </control>\r\n <operation>\r\n  <authentication>\r\n   <login>\r\n    <userid>XXX</userid>\r\n    <companyid>XXXX</companyid>\r\n    <password>XXXX</password>\r\n   </login>\r\n  </authentication>\r\n\r\n<content>\r\n <function controlid=\"testControlId\">\r\n  <readByQuery>\r\n    <object>CUSTOMER</object>\r\n    <query/>\r\n  </readByQuery>\r\n </function>\r\n</content>\r\n </operation>\r\n</request>";
    System.out.println(urlParameters);
      url = new URL(targetURL);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
           "application/xml");

      connection.setUseCaches (false);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      //Send request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                  connection.getOutputStream ());
      wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
      wr.flush ();
      wr.close ();

      //Get Response    
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        System.out.println(line);
        response.append('\r');
      }
      rd.close();
      return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;

    } finally {

      if(connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect(); 
      }
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: What failure response are you getting?

Comment: What kind of failure? What kind of response?

Comment: <response>
      <control><status>failure</status>
            <senderid></senderid><controlid></controlid>
      </control> <errormessage>
            <error>
                  <errorno></errorno>
                  <description></description>
                  <description2></description2>
                  <correction></correction>
            </error>
            <error>
                  <errorno></errorno>
                  <description></description>
                  <description2></description2>
                  <correction></correction> </error>      </errormessage></response>

Comment: When I pass that https://XXXX.html in the browser.I am getting the same as the erroresponse

Comment: This isn't your first question on this network @Karthi, you should know better

Comment: Sorry. Are you talking about posting question in a proper way?. Will avoid this future